# PyCrypto Dependency issue with py3compat

Tags: python, pycrypto

I have `pycrypto 2.6.1` installed but I still get this error when trying to import`RSA`.

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 73, in <module>
ImportError: No module named py3compat
>>>
```

As you can see, there is no problem trying to import AES but an issue when trying to import RSA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to all my site-packages packages being owned by root.

I got around this issue by installing everything locally (for the current user) like this:

`pip install pycrypto --user`

and this way I had all my packages automatically install without any problems.